# Creating a class for JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
    "Code": 2, 
    "Body": {
        "Dynamic-Key": {
            "Key1": "Val1", 
            "Key2": "Val2"
        }
    }
}
```

Defining the following classes structure:

```
[DataContract]
class JsonResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string  Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public JsonResponseBody Body { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
class JsonResponseBody
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Dynamic-Key")]
    public DynamicKeyData Data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
class DynamicKeyData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

I can deserialize the given JSON with the following code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonResponse));
JsonResponse responseData = serializer.ReadObject(responseStream) as JsonResponse;
```

However in my case the **"Dynamic-Key"** is not known and is defined by user input value.
What is the right way to handle this kind of JSON definition?

**Considerations:**

The JSON is of a third party Api, so changing it is not an option.

In my case I don't care about the Dynamic-Key name, so if there is an option to always map to one generic name it will do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you definitely need to use WCF? Otherwise I'd recommend looking at [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). There's a number of extensibility mechanisms such as [Contract Resolvers](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Store the JSON in a string let suppose in strResult.
Then you can deserialize it into the JsonResponse object as follows:

JsonConvert is the class in Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert  dll. You can use it as follows:

```
JsonResponse object= (JsonResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResult,  typeof(JsonResponse));
```